# Best practice for sending image files to server (Web app development in Worklight 6.2)

Tags: http, web, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a requirement to send images to a server, the minimum number of images to be sent are 10 and it can increase, these images are camera captures and can be of low or high resolution images. These images are required for image processing in the server side.

What's the best practice for sending these files to the server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Worklight adapters. They were not meant for media transfer (be it images or movies).
2. Cordova supplies File API, so you can use it coupled with base64 encoding/decoding on the client and server, together with AJAX calls to send the data string or later processing.

Some related questions:

- [How to send images through Worklight server without base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789628/how-to-send-images-through-worklight-server-without-base64-encoding)
- [post image using worklight http adapter proper format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249707/post-image-using-worklight-http-adapter-proper-format)

The topic was asked several times in the past, so best to search through some more questions.